# Writing SSH server over TCP

Tags: java, sockets, authentication, encryption, ssh

For the learning purposes I am trying to figure out how SSH protocol works. Unfortunately, there's a little information across the internet (e.g. comparing to WebSocket protocol) so I am following [RFC 4253 - The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253).

---

On the client side I am using Git Bash (just for test) and a simple clone command which works over SSH protocol:

```
git clone git@localhost:test/test.git
```

On the server side I have the TCP socket opened on port 22 and the following code snippet to parse incoming data:

```
public class TestSSH {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(22);
        Socket client = server.accept();
        InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        String versionExchange = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("VERSION EXCHANGE: " + versionExchange);
        writer.println("SSH-2.0-TestSSH_1.0");
        writer.flush();

        int packetLength = fetchPacketLength(inputStream);
        System.out.println("PACKET LENGTH: " + packetLength);

        int paddingLength = inputStream.read();
        System.out.println("PADDING LENGTH: " + paddingLength);

        int payloadLength = packetLength - paddingLength - 1;
        byte[] payload = fetch(inputStream, payloadLength);
        System.out.println("PAYLOAD: " + payload.length + " bytes");
        System.out.println(new String(payload, "UTF-8"));

        byte[] randomPadding = fetch(inputStream, paddingLength);
        System.out.println("RANDOM PADDING: " + randomPadding.length);
        server.close();
    }

    private static int fetchPacketLength(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        int length = ((inputStream.read() & 0xFF) << 24);
        length |= ((inputStream.read() & 0xFF) << 16);
        length |= ((inputStream.read() & 0xFF) << 8);
        length |= (inputStream.read() & 0xFF);
        return length;
    }

    private static byte[] fetch(InputStream inputStream, int length) throws IOException{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (byte) inputStream.read();
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to **read actual SSH key for authentication** on the server side.

At this point I have the following output:

```
VERSION EXCHANGE: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
PACKET LENGTH: 1844
PADDING LENGTH: 10
PAYLOAD: 1833 bytes
D^?>?$??   ?curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384...
RANDOM PADDING: 10
```

If I understand it correctly - the payload should contain ciphers to decrypt MAC (target SSH key), but the payload itself is a long string and it's corrupted at the head with some undecodable bytes which makes me feeling I am doing something wrong. Moreover I don't know how much bytes should I read until the end of the MAC.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand it correctly - the payload should contain ciphers to decrypt MAC (target SSH key)

The first packet contains `SSH_MSG_KEXINIT` packet ([*7.1.  Algorithm Negotiation*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1) in RFC).

> but the payload itself is a long string and it's corrupted at the head with some undecodable bytes which makes me feeling I am doing something wrong.

As from the RFC,. It is not text protocol, but binary. First bytes have this meaning:

```
byte         SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
byte[16]     cookie (random bytes)
name-list    kex_algorithms
name-list    server_host_key_algorithms
```

> Moreover I don't know how much bytes should I read until the end of the MAC.

It is described few lines later:

> Each of the algorithm name-lists **MUST be a comma-separated list** of algorithm names (see Algorithm Naming in [SSH-ARCH] and additional information in [SSH-NUMBERS]).  Each supported (allowed) algorithm MUST be listed in order of preference, from most to least.

From my run of `tcpdump`, it looks like the fields are separated by two NULL bytes:

```
[...]
0x0110:  656c 6c6d 616e 2d67 726f 7570 312d 7368  ellman-group1-sh
0x0120:  6131 0000 0167 6563 6473 612d 7368 6132  a1...gecdsa-sha2
0x0130:  2d6e 6973 7470 3235 362d 6365 7274 2d76  -nistp256-cert-v
[...]
```